# Accessing locally hosted site through public ip

Tags: python, django, apache

I have setup a django app on a apache server in a VM. The site is accessible when I use the apache server IP in the VM browser. It is also accessible from the host browser through it's local IP. But, I cannot access it through the public IP over the internet. I get a `site can't be reached` error
I have set up port forwarding such that:
1. All router requests on port 80 are forwarded to local IP
2. All requests to local IP on port 80 are forwarded to the VM

I checked if my port is open on my public ip using http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
It says that my port is closed. Same results with http://canyouseeme.org/

I am able to ping my public ip successfully.
I have tried disabling all my firewalls but this has not helped. Please tell me if you need any code to be shared. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Extra information: It seems my router's WAN IP is different from my public IP. I can access the site through the WAN IP from the host browser but again, I am not able to access it over the internet.

Comment: Can you try running a small server directly on you machine and not in VM and then try?
It definitely must be blocked somewhere in the network from Your Local to VM

Comment: If the problem was between the Local and the VM, I would not be able to access the site in my local, right? But I am able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a public IP address or push your application to the hosting (like this for example https://gpdhost.com/offers/).

ToDo: learn DMZ, learn WAN-LAN packet forwarding process, learn TCP/IP routing, learn public and private IP addressing and learn NAT.

Description: http/https connection conversation (client-outside vs your-server):
1) client: in browser write: sharan-site/;
2) get IP by DNS name from public servers? But public servers don't know your ip:dns-name pair...
=> fail
next example:
1) client: 192.168.1.1/ - where IP is your server
2) so where is it?
=> nowhere, it is private IP address! Fail...

Desc+: Port forwarding it is NAT feature. Your router must have public IP address, and you must setup DMZ like scheme in your local network: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/13772-12.html

Desc++: that sites check outside tcp/80 port on your router and PC, and it's open, no questions... But this no help for your task.

Comment: I have a public IP address. I am trying to access the site through the public IP address. I have setup DMZ on the router but same problem persists.
Also, those sites are telling me the port is closed! Not open.

Comment: Check router forwarding rules? Ping from outside? Router config?

Comment: Router forwarding enabled for required port. "Ping from outside?"?

Comment: Available your public IP from any host in Internet for pinging or trace? May be forwarding working wrong? I can't say something about this without knowing router config...

Comment: I checked the router config. Seems my WAN IP is different from my public IP. How can I deal with the problem then? Is there a .config file or something similar for the router that I can share? If not, please mention what exact information you need

Comment: 1) draw your network scheme in in Visio or http://draw.io/, and show here; 2) trace from outside Internet your IP, that as you thinking, must be accessible from there (you can do this from any other Internet channel, for example share your cell phone modem to laptop or from it self)